# Formula #name error when inserted from scripts. Pasted directly to the sheet works

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on google apps script with sheets. I created a function, chosen from added menu inserts rows and fills particular cells with formulas. 
I copied my perfectly working sheet to another and moved the GAS code as well. In the second sheet when I call the function everything works ok but the formulas that are inserted return #name error for the "if". The syntax and spelling are ok - the formula works in other cells. 
I'm in Poland and so my gues is some difference in parsing but I have no clue how to fix it.

I pasted the formula from the script directly into the cells and formula bar and th

it worked.

This is part of my code:

```
  function nowyOkres() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var iloscWierszy = 9;


  var komurkiDatyPoczatkowej = sh.getRange("T2:T8");
  var komurkiDatyKoncowej = sh.getRange("U2:U8");
  var formatDatyPoczatkowej = 
   '=JEŻELI(ORAZ(NIE(CZY.PUSTA(A2));NIE(CZY.PUSTA(A2))); 
  ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(TEKST(A2;"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEKST(A2;"hh:mm:ss"));"Bez_daty")';
  var formatDatyKoncowej = '=JEŻELI(ORAZ(NIE(CZY.PUSTA(C2)); 
  NIE(CZY.PUSTA(A2)));ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(TEKST(A2;"mm/dd/yyyy")&" 
  "&TEKST(B2+C2;"hh:mm:ss"));"Bez_daty")';

  sh.insertRows(2,iloscWierszy+1);
  komurkiFormul.setFormulas(formuly);
  komurkiSumy.setValues(sumyKolumn);
  komurkiDatyPoczatkowej.setFormula(formatDatyPoczatkowej); 
  komurkiDatyPoczatkowej.setFormula(formatDatyPoczatkowej);
  komurkiDatyKoncowej.setFormula(formatDatyKoncowej );

}
```

Comment: There are some differences between the Polish and English formula. The polish only uses the cell A3 and the english A4 and B4.

Comment: Don't use line breaks in script strings.

Comment: The date and time (TEKST(A2;"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEKST(A2;"hh:mm:ss") are pointing to the same cell (A2), so this is not correct. Have you tried joining those strings in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem.

Comment: var formatDatyPoczatkowej = '=JEŻELI(ORAZ(NIE(CZY.PUSTA(A2));NIE(CZY.PUSTA(B2))); ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(TEKST(A2;"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEKST(B2;"hh:mm:ss"));"Bez_daty")';
  var formatDatyKoncowej = '=JEŻELI(ORAZ(NIE(CZY.PUSTA(C2)); NIE(CZY.PUSTA(A2)); NIE(CZY.PUSTA(B2)));ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(TEKST(A2;"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEKST(B2+C2;"hh:mm:ss"));"Bez_daty")';

Comment: Sorry, You are right with the mistakes in the formulas they are corrected above. The problem still remains. Right now when I edit the populated formula cells the error disappears.

Answer (score -1):

Since it’s a bit difficult to determine what is causing the issue, I recommend you to try the same via script:

```
 var a1 = sh.getRange('A1');

  var a4 = sh.getRange('A4').getDisplayValue();
  var b4 = sh.getRange('B4').getDisplayValue();

  if (a4 != null && b4 != null){
    var c = a4 + " " + b4;

    a1.setValue(c)

  }
```

Please let me know your results

**EDIT**

It looks like there is an issue with the polish syntax which causes this error.
I tested it with `.setValues()` and `.setFormula()` and both work in english at the first try, but in polish it gives an error until you manually edit the cell. 
[I'm reporting this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140848153), but for now I recommend you to do the formulas in english.

Comment: Your solution is, of course, more elegant and reliable. But I'm afraid that it only opens my "Pandora's box". The whole idea for cells with formerly mentioned formula was to get a valid date from my sheet data to reuse in calendar. Because I'm a begginer I still have problems with date manegment in GAS, hence the cell population which outputs corect date format. I heve repicated the populating part in a separate sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wg8DD7MMrwJm4VEC3mRfTw41OV2zhjjY1uuquCuyAjM/edit?usp=sharing). The formula still has to be repasted manually.

Comment: Thank You for Your edit. I tried to use English syntax and it returns:formula analyze error. It is in the "polish ver."of Google Sheets. In the example file [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wg8DD7MMrwJm4VEC3mRfTw41OV2zhjjY1uuquCuyAjM/edit?usp=sharing) above that is on my English version of Google Drive the Polish ver returns #name error. English works great. Is there some variable that sets up the whole environment in a certain language. I feel beaten by the scripts right now. But maybe it will help me to deal with dates in the end ;) Never the less thank You for Your efforts.

Comment: where did You report the bug?

Comment: I reported the bug in issuetracker.google.com, but for some reason they decided to keep it internal, so it can't be tracked from outside a @google account.

Comment: Thank You never the less ;)

Comment: I added a public bug also in Issue Tracker (see edit). It will be updated at the same time as the bug reported in July.